# Numba: performance issue because of return statement

Tags: python, numba

New to NUMBA and checking its performance enhancement. Perplexed by this issue that if you use the **return  val** statement, in the go_fast() function, NUMBA doesn't show any performance enhancement. Is my understanding incorrect?

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = int(10e7); b = int(a**0.5); count = 100
x = np.arange(a).reshape(b, b)

from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def go_fast(a): # Function is compiled and runs in machine code
    def inner(a):
        trace = 0.0
        for i in range(a.shape[0]):
            trace += np.tanh(a[i, i])
        return a + trace
    for i in range(count): val = inner(a)
    # return val

# DO NOT REPORT THIS... COMPILATION TIME IS INCLUDED IN THE EXECUTION TIME!
start = time.time()
val = go_fast(x)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (with compilation) = %s" % (end - start))

# NOW THE FUNCTION IS COMPILED, RE-TIME IT EXECUTING FROM CACHE
start = time.time()
go_fast(x)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (after compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
exit()
```

Comment: If you don't return anything then your function does nothing, so the compiler is free to optimize it away.

Comment: Why do you expect numba to be faster here? If most of the time spent calculating `tanh`, how could numba improve it?

Comment: This example is given in the first page of numba tutorial website (without return val expression). Also, I'm unable to see any difference between the pure python run time and run with @jit(nopython = True) decorator. Just wondering if you guys are experiencing the same...

Answer (score 0):

When the function returns nothing, after the initial compilation, the optimizer figures out to skip over it. However, adding `return val` should still show a significant performance improvement!

The reason why you aren't seeing any *apparent* improvement is because there is a massive bottleneck in the operation `return a + trace` in `inner()`. Here `a` is a massive array with 10e7 values, and each time `inner()` is called, the addition of those 10e7 values at end consumes so much time that it overshadows the optimization numba is making on the loops.

So here's what you can do to verify the performance improvement: Firstly, you can change `return a + trace` to just `return trace`.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def go_fast(a): # Function is compiled and runs in machine code
    def inner(a):
        trace = 0.0
        for i in range(a.shape[0]):
            trace += np.tanh(a[i, i])
        return trace
    for i in range(count): val = inner(a)
    return val
```

This immediately shows about a 50x gain on my system.

```
Elapsed (with compilation) = 0.20658421516418457
Elapsed (after compilation) = 0.004923343658447266
```

Alternatively, because the bottleneck is in `a`, a smaller size of `a` would also help you see past the bottleneck and verify numba's performance gain.

```
a = int(10e3); b = int(a**0.5); count = 100
x = np.arange(a).reshape(b, b)

from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def go_fast(a): # Function is compiled and runs in machine code
    def inner(a):
        trace = 0.0
        for i in range(a.shape[0]):
            trace += np.tanh(a[i, i])
        return a + trace
    for i in range(count): val = inner(a)
    return val
```

For `a` = 10e3, the timings show:

```
Elapsed (with compilation) = 0.38916540145874023
Elapsed (after compilation) = 0.0008070468902587891
```

If we scale `a` up to 10e5, we get:

```
Elapsed (with compilation) = 0.558464527130127
Elapsed (after compilation) = 0.17211246490478516
```

And at 10e7, the difference isn't visible at all.